# How to set up ProxMox 1.9 on VPN?

Tags: debian, vpn

I am trying to set up a ProxMox virtualization platform in an existing network.

The network currently consists of several servers which have VMWare free edition.

There is some sort of VPN defined in switch. In order for VMWare management interface to be accessible from network, there needs to be ticked a checkbox in the VMWare mgmt interface network settings for VPN and entered the VPN id.

I didn't notice any such configuration option during ProxMox installation, so my Proxmox VE on the same physical server, using same manual IP settings (ip/nm/gw),  is not accessible.

As I understand I should touch the Proxmox's underlying Debian config in /etc/network/interfaces, but I have no idea, what should I aim for: do I specify the settings for eth0, do I make a virtual interface? How to make it accessible for both ProxMox VE and underlying future VMs? I read the ProxMox installation guide, but unfortunately it presumes better understanding of VPNs than I have.

A config template or similar would be appreciated.

Disclaimer: I have only rudimentary knowledge of VPNs. I would love to learn about them  properly, however, at the moment I really need to make stuff work on short notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In general:**

1. you must have kernel with compiled or module 8021q available.

   modprobe 8021q
2. Set up eth0 without IP.

   ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up
3. add VLAN:

   vconfig add eth0 {your_VLAN_number for example 111}
4. ifconfig the new vlan interface normally:

   ifconfig eth0.111 {ip} netmask {nm}  up

Ofc, you still have to add the default gw as usual.

**Proxmox specific addendum:**

In order for this to work with Proxmox, you need to pass this to its vmbr0 or similar interface that you have defined in Proxmox config and that it will use to bridge with the virtual machines' interfaces.

In the end, it goes something like this:

eth0 up no ip -> eth0.vlan_id up no ip -> vmbr0 with main ip you wanted in the first place

/etc/network/interfaces thus looks like this (assuming VLAN id is 1111):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  192.168.1.100
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        gateway  192.168.1.1
        bridge_ports eth0.1111
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

That's it. I don't actually see whether vconfig added the VLAN info to some system config, but this appears to work through restarts and no other identifiable changes except to the /etc/network/interfaces file.